# Does a representation $d=a^2-2b^2$ with coprime integers always exist?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I studied which differences $a-b$ are possible in primitive pythagorean triples $(a/b/c)$.

I noticed that the difference $d$ must be odd and contains only prime factors with quadratic residue $2$, in other words primes of the form $8k\pm 1$.

My conjecture is that this condition is also sufficient. To prove that I need the following :

> Every prime $p$ of the form $8k\pm 1$ can be written as $p=a^2-2b^2$ (Infinite descent might be a possibility to prove it)
>
> If two numbers $m,n$ are of the form $a^2-2b^2$ with coprime integers $a,b$, then so is the product $mn$.

I found out the idendity $$(a^2-2b^2)(c^2-2d^2)=(ac+2bd)^2-2(ad+bc)^2$$ which could be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express a prime $p$ as $p=a^2-2b^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790599/express-a-prime-p-as-p-a2-2b2)

Comment: @lulu This answers one part, but what about the part with the coprime integers ? Aditionally, a proof not using Thue's lemma would be nice.

Comment: I thought that followed from the general theory, but trying to write it out I don't see how to prove it. Seems easy to prove that the only primes which divide both $ac+2bd,ad+bc$ must also divide $m$ and $n$.  Not sure how to finish from there.